# ReadConsoleOutputCharacter - what parameters i need to use?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

i'm learning programming in c++ and i'm making small program using windows.h library.
I need a function in my program which will read from console a single character from specific cell.
So there is this ReadConsoleOutputCharacter function which does what i want but i don't understand what second parameter should look like.

This one as described on microsoft website:

*Out* LPTSTR  lpCharacter

If someone could provide some simple example of using such function with reading single or multiple cells it would be great.

Thanks in advance for all the help and i hope my english is understandable at least.

Comment: And what does the microsoft website say about the parameter?

Comment: Well that's where i have problem. I read it but i don't quite understand it. 
From microsoft:  
pCharacter [out]
A pointer to a buffer that receives the characters read from the console screen buffer.
The storage for this buffer is allocated from a shared heap for the process that is 64 KB in size. The maximum size of the buffer will depend on heap usage.

Comment: Here is a MSDN example of [using the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-and-writing-blocks-of-characters-and-attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *lpCharacter* [out]
>   A pointer to a buffer that receives the characters
>   read from the console screen buffer.
>
> The storage for this buffer is allocated from a shared heap for the
>   process that is 64 KB in size. The maximum size of the buffer will
>   depend on heap usage.

So, when it reads the characters where do you want it to put the characters it read?

You should have a variable for holding the characters and for *lpCharacter* you pass the address of this variable.

The second paragraph is indeed confusing. It doesn't seem to have any relevance to this function. I ignored it.

Of course if you are trying to read more than one character at a time then you will need an array to hold the characters, and pass the address of the start of the array.

Comment: So if i want to read only 1 cell then char variable is ok right?

Comment: @Hrot Yes, unless you have unicode enabled, in which case it would be wchar_t (as with all Windows functions; if you're using chars for all the other functions then that also applies to this one)

Comment: Hmm ok, i get it now. Thanks for help.

Comment: The second paragraph applies to versions prior to Windows 8. The old implementation of the console API used an LPC port to communicate between the client and console host process (e.g. conhost.exe in Windows 7, and csrss.exe in previous versions). LPC messages have a small maximum size. For larger messages (e.g. reading from the console screen buffer), a 64K section of memory is shared between the server and client, which is managed as a runtime library heap. Windows 8 switched to using the ConDrv device instead of LPC, so the warnings about heap size no longer apply.

Comment: @eryksun Okay, so it's trying to say that the maximum number of bytes you can read is quite small. But what it actually does say is that you have to allocate the buffer you pass for this parameter from a special heap. But that is not correct.

Comment: Yes, the person who wrote this was thinking about the intermediary storage limit, which is a limit imposed by the internal implementation prior to Windows 8. It could have been written more clearly.